# ag-grid-angular: Re-render a specific header

Tags: filter, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid-angular to render a data, the first column header consists of '+' button which is hidden when user edits any records.

**Normal Mode**

[image]

**Edit Mode**

[image]

When user tries to filter when in edit mode, edit mode must be cancelled.

In filterOpened event, I do:

```
onFilterOpened(filterOpenedEvent: FilterOpenedEvent): void {
       this.gridContext.editingRowId = undefined;
       filterOpenedEvent.api.clearFocusedCell();
       filterOpenedEvent.api.refreshHeader();
}
```

The issue is this will close the filter window. I want just the first column's header to be re-rendered. Is there any way to do it.

NOTE:

1. I am ok to have the '+' button rendered even after the filter is
   closed, but did not get any 'closed' event.
2. The '+' button is handled/rendered in a Component that implements
   IHeaderAngularComp. The html of which is like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="gridContext.editingRowId === null || gridContext.editingRowId === undefined">
  <icon id="add" (click)="onAddNewRow()" ></icon>
</ng-container>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarise your issue: when the user is editing a cell and they open the filter menu, edit mode should be cancelled.

I'd recommend calling `api.stopEditing()` inside `onFilterOpened`

As per the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-editing-stopEditing):

> If a cell is editing, it stops the editing. Pass true if you want to
> cancel the editing (i.e. don't accept changes). [See Editing API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editing/#editing-api).

Comment: Thanks Shuheb. But, this does not work as using 'api.stopEditing()' will close the filter popup

Comment: Please provide a sample to reproduce this issue.